# How to list the path filename in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, fs

I would like to know how to search through all files,

if the keyword `testsample` is found,

then console log the pathname in nodejs,

How to read and search the keyword, display the path in nodejs

```
//app.js
var app = express();
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  } 
  files.forEach(function (file) {
      console.log(file); 
  });
});
```

Assuming the directory structure is like this

```
/path/to/your/dir
  - dir1
    - module1
      - file1.js
  - dir2
    - anotherdir
      - another_dir1
        - index.js
      - index.js
    - index.js
  - dir3
    - file2.js

Expected Output

below path contains the keyword


/path/to/your/dir/dir1/module1/file1.js
/path/to/your/dir/dir2/anotherdir/another_dir1/index.js
/path/to/your/dir/dir2/anotherdir/index.js
/path/to/your/dir/dir2/index.js
/path/to/your/dir/dir3/file2js
```

Comment: This problem has been solved thousands of times.  A simple search would find many code examples here and many modules on NPM that do this for you.  If you're writing it yourself, you check each entry you get from `readdir()` and if it's a directory, then you recurse into it.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you please help,

Comment: The programming tool `grep` should be able to do this just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should do !!

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
        return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }   
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        console.log(file); 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I have used the code, donknow how to check the keyword in the file and list the path,

Comment: You want to filter the file names based on search term ?? because keywords searching will not be possible without any meta data for the files